# I can't figure out the actual meaning of draft in this context. I checked in the dictionary but the meaning that go with it looks inconspicuous

Tags: word-usage, difference, vocabulary

Spray only in an area free of **drafts**. **Drafts** create overspray. Overspray is not visible, but it does result in a rough surface that can be fixed only by a final sanding with fine-grit #320 or #220 sandpaper

Answer (score 5):

Check the definitions for [draught](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/draught), some are spelled "draft" in the US.

In this case,

> A **draught** is a current of air that comes into a place in an undesirable way.

Answer (score 3):

From Merriam-Webster, the  11a definition  of [draft](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draft):

*a current of air in a closed-in space*

If you are spraying something, the particles flow in a certain direction, but if there is wind blowing nearby, they will flow in another direction.